# Shopware6 confirm registration can't match shopware-shop-signature

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

We are developing our app following the steps described in here:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide

We successfully implemented the first call with the indicated checks over the "shopware-app-signature".
We have problem doing the same with the second call (the confirm-registration). The flow works fine, but we are not able to recalculate the "shopware-shop-id" as suggested in the documentation.
There is an example done in php. Given the following body:

```
{
  "apiKey":"SWIARXBSDJRWEMJONFK2OHBNWA",
  "secretKey":"Q1QyaUg3ZHpnZURPeDV3ZkpncXdSRzJpNjdBeWM1WWhWYWd0NE0",
  "timestamp":"1592398983",
  "shopUrl":"http:\/\/my.shop.com",
  "shopId":"sqX6cqHi6hbj",
  "shopSecret":"b49b082162c95b8afd322dffcc82b3550a64ad5b06a05813d431090d32a4b5f3"
}
```

the doc suggests to recalculate the "shopware-shop-signature" like this:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

/** @var RequestInterface $request */
$hmac = \hash_hmac('sha256', $request->getBody()->getContents(), $shopSecret);
```

Our server is written in JS with node, and we tried to replicate the hmac calculation like this:

```
createHmac("sha256", shopSecret).update(request.rawBody).digest("hex");
```

where "shopSecret" is the one created in the first call and "request.rawBody" is the raw json request body.
Unfortunately this never matches the "shopware-shop-signature" in the request headers.
Do you have any suggestion on where we are doing wrong?

A little side note: with the app in development mode (with the secret in the manifest.xml) the previous body of the confirm-registration never sends back the "shopSecret", so we have to recalculate it. Is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been similar questions regarding authentication/confirmation on node-based servers before. So far the issues always were always caused by either differences in escaping or decoding within either the request body or the query parameters.

I think in your instance the problem could be that in your `request.rawBody` the `http:\/\/my.shop.com` string automatically is unescaped to `http://my.shop.com`. This causes the keys generated in Shopware and on your end to be hashed differently, making the comparison fail. Make sure the slashes stay escaped.
For reference see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553516/8556259).

FYI: If, in your later development, you'll have problems with authentication of `GET` requests, note that url encoded query parameters must not be decoded by your node server or the authentication will fail, also due to differing hashes.
For reference see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75149366/8556259).